# Java library to create PDF from LaTeX source

Tags: java, pdf, latex, tex

I have Java program, which receives some data and generates LaTeX document.

I need Java library to create PDF file from generated LaTeX source.

Could you recommend me something, please?

Comment: Any reason why you can't invoke a LaTeX compiler from Java and have LaTeX generate the PDF itself?

Comment: @kurtzbot I would like to write a self-consistent program, which can be executed on every computer without installing third-party software.

Comment: It's too bad that this question is closed, because I can't leave an answer.  I found the following: http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/page/ServerUsage/ , which is based on a more low-level http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/ .  I haven't used these libraries, however, so I don't know yet how well they'll address this problem.

Comment: JLatexMath is on Maven Central, JMathTex is not; both are GPLv2.  Another alternative is to run MathJax in Rhino (Javascript library, renders LaTeX and MathML, well supported by the mathematics community, Apache 2.0 license).

Comment: @JimPivarski Thank you anyway for your late answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with kurtzbot, LaTeX compilers are sophisticated pieces of software which cannot reasonably be rewritten in Java or any other language. If it were it would be a massive effort. To my knowledge there isn't even a C library implementing the compiler, one must us a command line program.

This is not to say that there aren't libraries which manage a build process, probably via system calls and monitoring temporary files (from the LaTeX build). For example, I know there is [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) which performs such a task. If someone has made a Java implementation like it, I would bundle a LaTeX compiler and that manager into your program.